# How to find hidden API

Tags: api, hidden

I want to see an api behind sync contacts. I tried to capture it with Burp, I am not able to see that api in burp, also with wireshark I try but the app is well obfuscated so I still cannot see it there.
Is there any way how can I capture the api that is responsible for sync contacts???

(As I see in device storage a database file is created and updated every time when I add new contact in app.)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to **decompile APK** and form source code you can find that API. if that application has a web version then you can get API from console and network request.

[here](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) is link for APK Decompile.

if you want the API that how to sync contact I can provide that API to you with source code, in Node or PHP with MySQL Database